# Custom icon when installing app from Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-apps-script

I've just been publishing my first script(s) on the Chrome Webstore.
The installation works fine, but the installed application shows up with the default (old) script icon - even though I've provided a custom icon.
Is there a way to use the custom icon for the installed application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a known issue and we are working hard at solving this. Stay tuned to the [Google Developers Live](https://developers.google.com/live/) for Apps Script hours or the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/release_notes).